# One to Many entity framework error

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, one-to-many, code-first, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 models, user & telephone. A user can have many telephone numbers.

My User code:

```
    public class User
    {
    public User()
     {
        this.TelephoneNumbers = new List<Telephone>();
     }
    public int UserId { get; set; }


    public string Forename { get; set; }


    public string Surname { get; set; }


    public string FirstLine { get; set; }


    public string Town { get; set; }


    public string County { get; set; }


    public string Postcode { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }


    public int TravelDistance { get; set; }
    //[Display (Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return Forename + " " + Surname; }
    }

    //List to store telephone numbers for the users
    public virtual ICollection<Telephone> TelephoneNumbers { get; set; }

}
```

My Telephone code:

```
    public class Telephone
    {
    public int TelephoneId { get; set; }

    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }


    //Used to get UserId from User table
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

   }
```

UserMap:

```
    public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
    public UserMap()
    {
        //Table Mapping
        this.ToTable("User");

        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(u => u.UserId);

        //Properties
        this.Property(u => u.UserId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(u => u.Forename)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(u => u.Surname)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

TelephoneMap

```
     public class TelephoneMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Telephone>
     {

    public TelephoneMap()
    {
        //Table Mapping
        this.ToTable("Telephone");

        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TelephoneId);

        //Properties
        this.Property(t => t.TelephoneId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.TelephoneNumber)
            .IsRequired();
       //Relationship
       //FK_Telephone_User
       //One to many relationship between user & telephone
       //One User has an iCollection of Telephone numbers
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.TelephoneNumbers)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
    }

}
```

I have ran  Add-Migration init followed by Update-Database.

I'm getting the following error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Telephone_dbo.User_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "API_Context-20150311183614", table "dbo.User", column 'UserId'`

I assume it is something to do with the UserId in my telephone model? Do I not need this to connect the two together when i'm seeding the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do. A telephone number is linked to a user through the foreign key. You need to specify whose telephone number is it, by specifying the user's id. The very fact that your constraint was broken was caused by one of the following possible reasons:

- not nullable foreign key (a telephone is always linked to the user, it should never float in the air)
- foreign key might have a default value, which does not exist in the user table

Anyway, if we talk about phone numbers and users, for me it seems implausible to make it nullable to prevent the error, as I do not see any use of phone numbers not linked to users, however, I do not know much about your project, therefore, my intuition might be faulty. So, you can solve the problem by making the foreign key nullable, but it seems the wrong approach. Instead, I believe your code should always specify the valid phone numbers.